Is there a way to toggle light and dark mode on lyx on windows 11
I want to have my windows 11 system default to dark mode but have lyx 2.4.1 always in the light mode, but regardless if I have use system colours checked or not lyx switches colour schemes when I change the system setting and I can't find a toggle to keep it in light mode.

It seems there isn't and the software is just bugged because the button to use system settings also doesn't do anything. Also the wiki for changing colours is out of date. Therefore, the best solution that I found was simply to set windows to light mode, open the preferences window, copy the colours that you want to change in dark mode then switch to dark mode and paste those colours in. Not an ideal solution, but that seems to be the state of lyx on windows
